# ANTLR won't parse this easy input for simple calculator grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, calculator, antlr3

```
grammar TestCSharpParser;


options {
  language=CSharp3;
}

@parser::namespace { Demo.Antlr }
@lexer::namespace { Demo.Antlr }

parse returns [double value]
  :  exp EOF {$value = $exp.value;}
  ;

exp returns [double value]
  :  addExp {$value = $addExp.value;}
  ;

addExp returns [double value]
  :  a=mulExp       {$value = $a.value;}
     ( '+' b=mulExp {$value += $b.value;}
     | '-' b=mulExp {$value -= $b.value;}
     )*
  ;

mulExp returns [double value]
  :  a=unaryExp       {$value = $a.value;}
     ( '*' b=unaryExp {$value *= $b.value;}
     | '/' b=unaryExp {$value /= $b.value;}
     )*
  ;

unaryExp returns [double value]
  :  '-' atom {$value = -1.0 * $atom.value;}
  |  atom     {$value = $atom.value;}
  ;

atom returns [double value]
  :  Number      {$value = Double.Parse($Number.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);}
  |  '(' exp ')' {$value = $exp.value;}
  ;

Number
  :  ('0'..'9')+ ('.' ('0'..'9')+)?
  ;

Space 
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n'){$channel = HIDDEN;}
  ;
```

---

The grammar won't parse the simple statement `4/5` or `(4/5)` tried this using ANTLRWorks.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? This to my mind should work correctly.

It keeps giving me the `NoViableAltException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several problems related to the use of the CSharp3 target.

- The CSharp2 and CSharp3 targets define the constant `Hidden` instead of `HIDDEN`
- ANTLRWorks cannot be used to generate parsers for grammars targeting the CSharp2 or CSharp3 targets. The parser must be generated either by MSBuild (preferred) or by using Antlr3.exe. These are documented on the [ANTLR 3 C# Releases](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3CSharpReleases) wiki page.
- ANTLRWorks cannot be used to test parsers generated for the CSharp2 or CSharp3 targets. Any results reported by the interpreter or debugger cannot be trusted.